# Want access of textfield from another .java file within a program

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have many .java files within my project. From FTall.java i want to access {text field} t1 ('main' jFrame -> jPanel2) of the FormTTS.java

[image: T1 is here]

I am right now getting errors due to that only, because it cannot find symbol t1.

It is private and i cant change it to public

Edit:
I am using this code already to open up FTall from the FormTTS.java:
In a button in FormTTS

```
     FTall forma = new FTall();
JFrame frame = forma.getFrame();
forma.setVisible(true);
```

and this in FTall

```
 public JFrame getFrame() {
     return jFrame1;
}
```

Comment: what is the visibility of that field..?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Please Help

Comment: @BlackPanther How does that matter? anyways it is visble. Had it not been visible, then also it should not have shown an error!

Comment: by visibility i mean the scope of the variable. is it public or private or protected or does it have a package level scope? since you said you are new i am not sure if you are having getters and setters or just creating fields with default or public access. if it is a private field and you are following conventions there should be a setter method for it, using which you can set the value provided you have the instance of that class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the way your code is structure, you need to supply some way for `FormTTS.t1`

In `FormTTS`, provide a method to exposes `t1`, something like `getMainTextField` for example...

```
public JTextField getMainTextField() {
    return t1;
}
```

You're next problem is `FTall` is going to need a reference to an instance of `FormTTS`.  Probably the easiest way would be to pass a reference to the constructor of `FTall`

```
private FormTTS mainForm;

public FTall(FormTTS mainForm) {
    this.mainForm= mainForm;
}
```

This will allow you to access `t1` by simply using the `mainForm` reference...

```
JTextField field = mainForm.getMainTextField();
```

Personally, I would prefer not to expose the text field as it gives too much access to callers, instead I'd prefer to `return` the text and if required provide a means to change it...

So in `FormTTS`, I might do something like...

```
public String getMainText() {
    return t1.getText();
}

// Do this only if you need to have write access
public void setMainText(String text) {
    t1.setText(text);
}
```

But that's just me...

To obtain the value, you would use a similar approach as above (to getting the text field)

```
String text = mainForm.getMainText();
```

Comment: Sir i would like to go with what you prefer, i do not want write access. You told me to write this: public `String getMainText() {
    return t1.getText();
}` in the FormTTS But what to write in FTall??? so that a variable in FTall gets the value of t1 from FormTTS

Comment: Sir in the line `String text = FormTTS.getMainText();` it shows an error -> non static method getMainText()  cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: That's not what I wrote.  You need a reference to an instance of `FormTTS`, this should be passed to `FTall` when it is created, that way you can access its methods and information, for the specific instance that you supply it

Comment: Sir i didnt get you; this is what you wrote right `String text = mainForm.getMainText();` and as mainForm is FormTTS; i wrote `String text = FormTTS.getMainText();` in FTall.java... If not this then what should the code be???

Comment: `mainForm` is an **instance** of `FormTTS`, there is a difference ;)

Comment: Sir so which of the code should i add for adding mainform. Because as of now i have just added  `public String getMainText() {
    return t1.getText();
}` in FormTTS and `String text = mainForm.getMainText();` in FTall so it shows an error in mainform in FTall

Comment: See the code below *"You're next problem is `FTall` is going to need a reference to an instance of `FormTTS`. Probably the easiest way would be to pass a reference to the constructor of `FTall`"*

Comment: If i want to similarly click a button then?

Comment: In this case you would need to expose it as `JButton` via a `getter` or supply a method that can perform the action for the caller

Answer (score 0):

if i am understanding your question its simple first ensure that your text field come in to scope before access and once it come in, then use a setter to set its refrence in required class then you can access it.

Comment: Hey i am a newbie and can't understand even a word you said. please be clear

Comment: create your field and ensure its scope, then pass the refrence of that field to your class by have a setter in it then you will get the reference of your created field when your required class come in to scope